# How to duplicate an object and rename the original to have the "_high" suffix and the duplicate the "_low" suffix

Tags: python, scripting

I'm trying to duplicate an object and add a _low to the duplicated object and _high to the one it was duplicated from. For example, if I had "cylinder" I want the duplicated object moved to the side to be "cylinder_low" and the one it was being duplicated from to be "cylinder_high"

```
import bpy
for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    suffixL = "_low"
    suffixH = "_high"
    act_obj = bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active
    
    bpy.ops.object.duplicate(linked=False, mode='TRANSLATION')
    obj.location[1] += 5
    
    if suffixL not in act_obj.name:
        act_obj.name = act_obj.name + suffixL
        
    
        
    elif suffixH not in act_obj.name:
        act_obj.name = act_object.name + suffixH
```

[image]

[image]

This is what I have but when I run it it works, but the original one is named "Cylinder.001" instead of with the suffix "_high".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For question code above put `act_obj = context.active_object` after the duplicate operator call.  Then it will be the duplicate of `obj`. if only one object is selected and active.

However also at play is the duplicate operator duplicates all selected objects. Try running with more than a single object selected.

You are only renaming the original `obj` if and when it is `act_obj`

However possibly much easier to use API calls and keep a ref to the newly created object and rename both based on original base name.

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context

for ob in context.selected_objects:
    name = ob.name
    copy = ob.copy()
    copy.data = copy.data.copy() # linked = False
    ob.name = f"{name}_high"
    copy.name = f"{name}_low"
    ob.location.x += 5
    context.collection.objects.link(copy)
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for this, this works exactly how I wanted it to